How does one get the ID from the response body with Mocha test, then use that ID and delete the item?
I am creating a location on the API, the location gets created but then populates an ID, this ID changes all the time. How do I write my Mocha tests to get the ID of the created location, even though the ID changes? Is there a way I can print this ID out?
Below is my test:
   describe("Create a location with all the crud information ", function () {
      it("It should return location crud successfully", async function () {
        request = getCreateLocationsRequest();
        response = await PostCreateLocation({
          token: accessToken,
          requestBody: request,
        });
        expect(response).to.not.be.empty;
        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
        expect(response.body.locations).to.not.be.empty;
        expect(response.body).to.have.property("locations");
        expect(response.body.location).to.have.property("id");
      });

This is the response if I run it in Postman.
{
    "location": {
        "id": 123,
        "internalId": 123,
        "codeId": null,
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "activeIntel": true,
        "selectable": true,
        "viewable": true, 
        "tfgid": 6,
        "polPrnttId": 123,
        "intPrntId": 123,
        "navPrntId": 123,
        "hgdID": 132,
        "country": "England",
        "lat": -10.33333333,
        "lon": 100.1,
        "kl2": "EN",
        "lka3": "SAA",
        "jklNumeric": "940",
        "notes": "my user notes1",
        "timeZone": "any",
        "lastUpdatedBy": "A Person",
        "lastUpdatedAt": "2024-11-04 11:57:55.212838+00",
        "deletedAt": null
    },}}

How do I assert or expect this ID and display it, so that I can pass it through my deleted tests?

It appears to be the response.body.location.id, which you're already asserting on.

understood but how would I collect the id then pass it through to the next test which is to be able to delete that created item.

Don't have tests depend on one another like that.

okay thank you, so I will create another describe or test to delete this item, in this test how can get the id, at the moment I can only see the id in the response from the previous above test. But in the next test, how will i be able to take the id from the response and use it to delete the id.
